# Finding if the subdomain URL is valid

Tags: 7, multi-sites, subsites

I have a multisite setup containing around 100 subdomains. I just want to redirect the user to parent website if a user enters an invalid subdomain. One way I thought was to access the $sites variable from sites.php but I didn't find a way to access that variable. Any help ?

Comment: For 100 subdomains. Did you need to create one by one in DNS or you had the Wildcard DNS record?

Comment: For now just using a wildcard :) That's why having a problem